# android make Action Bar activity change independent

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my app i have Action Bar(ActionBarSherlock). I would like to make that Action Bar static/global something like System Bar for my application, so when switching between activities only rest of view is set.

Is that possible to do when switching between activities and any ideas how to do that ?

Comment: Use Fragments and google before you ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that is not possible but you can use Fragments that support 8 API 8+ From the actionBarSherlock Library thats not a big problem just do a little research.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You are welcome to have one activity and switch your UI via something like fragments, though.

Comment: But as i know fragments are only from API 11, should do API 8+

Comment: @kort.es: The Android Support package has a backport of fragments working back to API Level 4.